# How to restrict a WebApi route parameter based on an array of possible values

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a WebApi v.2 method for the following route:

```
[Route("api/{entityName}/logo/{entityId}/{size:char}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetLogo(string entityName, string entityId, char size) {...}
```

Now, I need to restrict `size` parameter to one of three characters: `s`, `m`, `l`. If `size` is not one of those, I don't want this route to be matched.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking that something like this may work

```
  [Route("api/{entityName}/logo/{entityId}/{size:regex(^[sml]?$)}")]
```

You can add a contstraint to a direct route using Shorthand References for Constraint Classes Used in Direct Route Templates.

A full list of the shorthand direct route regular expression classes can be found here

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Stack overflow previous question similar topic
[Regex in Route attribute - RESTful API ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077406/regex-in-route-attribute-restful-api-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!