# Routes in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My requirement is I need to set multiple routes to same controller/action method.

If user enters url http://localhost:xxxx/home/index , it will target "index" action method of "home" controller.

I also want "http://localhost:xxxx/products" and "http://localhost:xxxx/categories" to point to "index" action method of "home" controller.

I was able to achive this by adding two routes "categories" and "products" as mentioned below , and it is working fine.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "categories",
      url: "categories",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "products",
      url: "products",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );


   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

My question is , is there any way I combine those two routes "categories" and "products" in to one ?

Comment: Short answer: No. (and since you do not have a segment for `{id}` in the first 2 routes, you may as well remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional`). Having said that you could create a route constraint but thats probably not worth it.

Comment: The regex filterin for the route attribute may be your friend here, i was able to do something very similar with it. Some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077406/regex-in-route-attribute-restful-api-asp-net-web-api

Comment: It would be clean if you could go for attribute routing (but not actually combining it) `[Route("Home/Index")]
    [Route("Products")]
    [Route("Categories")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }`

Comment: @ Developer , MVC 5 supports attribute routing ?

Comment: @CleanCrispCode - it does - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: @CleanCrispCode - Make sure you enable attribute routing in route config - `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` I had put this as answer, but later realized that my answer will not actually "combine" the routes as you were looking for and hence deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a constraint to your route.

Make the entire path a parameter, and then assign a regular expression rule to match this parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "IndexMapper",
    url: "{alternateIndexName}",
    defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Index" },
    constraints: new { alternateIndexName="(categories)|(products)"}
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_6